# How to read the file data from GIT Repo. without cloning it in local using JGIT API

Tags: java, git, jgit

I tried to find a way to fetch particular file data from GIT Repo. without cloning that file in local using JGit API but didn't found anything related to this. Now , I doubt is there any built in function available in JGit API to allow remote server viewing?

Please can anyone guide me on this?

Edit-1: My GIT repo. is hosted on BitBucket.

Comment: Except for `archive`/`fetch`/`pull`/`push`/`ls-remote` Git doesn't provide a way to work with remote repositories. Either you clone it locally or use other, out-of-git ways like Github/Gitlab API or any other non-git remote access like ssh or network filesystem.

Comment: Hi, My Git repo. is hosted on Bitbucket. Is there any specific API which I can use to read the data remotely without cloning the repo.?

Comment: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/downloads/%7Bfilename%7D

Comment: 1) its not possible in plain Git 2) use bitbucket rest api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*JGit* is just a wrapper for automating *Git* specific tasks. If its not available in Git then it shouldn't be available in *JGit* either. File download is not a Git specific feature, its more like a Git Repository Provider specific feature; for example, Bitbucket and GitHub provides this feature.

Since your repository is hosted on Bitbucket then you should look into their [File Download Rest API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/downloads/%7Bfilename%7D#get). You should try to make a custom wrapper for automating this cURL request:

`curl -s -L https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/downloads/{file-name}`